# How do I subscribe to the Stack Exchange podcast using the Zune software?

Tags: podcasts, zune

The Stack Exchange podcast is hosted by SoundCloud.  The title says the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[They discuss an issue with the StackOverflow podcast here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/subscribing-to-the-stackoverflow-podcast-with-zune-player).

They came to the conclusion that the following link worked:

blog.stackoverflow.com/?feed=podcast

for the StackOverflow podcast. I changed the stackoverflow to stackexchange and it seems to be correct.

**Try this:** blog.stackexchange.com/?feed=podcast

Comment: this stopped working :/

Answer (score 0):

On my Android phone using the Google listen app, I had to enter the following in full to get it to work:

```
http://blog.stackexchange.com/index.php?feed=podcast
```